# Hamiltonian and Lagrangian classical mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems

Is the following logic correct?:

If you have an Hamiltonian, that has time has a variable explicitly, and you get the Lagrangian $L$ from it, and then you get an equivalent $L'$, since $L$ has the total time derivate of a function, both Lagrangians will lead to the same equations Euler-Lagrange equations right?
If so, and if you get you get  the Hamiltonian from $L'$, and  you find the Hamilton equations from it will they be equal to the original Hamiltonian's Hamilton equations?

If it is of any help, the given Hamiltonian is:

$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} - bqpe^{-\alpha t} + \frac{ba}{2}e^{-\alpha t}(\alpha + b e^{-\alpha t}) + \frac{kq^2}{2} \, .$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems OP is essentially asking the following two questions:

> 1. Is the [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) an [involutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) transformation?

*Answer:*

- The answer is *Yes* in the regular case, i.e. when there is a bijective correspondence $v\leftrightarrow p$ between velocities and momenta. This follows from the symmetric form $$H+L =p_i v^i$$ of the Legendre transformation. See also. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105912/2451) related Phys.SE post.
- The singular case (where typically [constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_constraint) are present) is more subtle, but for physically meaningful situations, it is usually still *Yes.*

> 2. Under a change of the  Lagrangian $$\widetilde{L}~=~ L +\frac{dF}{dt},$$
>      by a total time-derivative, after a Legendre transformation into the Hamiltonian formulation, are the corresponding Hamilton's equations un-changed?

*Answer:* Well, the function $F$ induces a [canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) (CT), so that Hamilton's equations turn into Kamilton's equations. This is the topic of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202330/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: but wont the first hamiltonian's hamiltion equation have time explicitly(since the given hamiltonian has time), whereas the second hamiltonian's  hamiltion equation not have time(because L' does not have time).  how can they be the same?

Comment: I updated the answer.