# Hamiltonian definitions in the presence of boundary term

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, boundary-terms

Consider a Lagrangian of the form

\begin{equation}
L(q,\dot{q})=L_1(q,\dot{q})+\frac{d L_2(q,\dot{q})}{dt}
\end{equation}

I understand that $\dot{L_2}$ does not modify the equations of motion, however, it modifies the boundary conditions needed to fulfill the variational principle $\delta L=0$.

Now consider the Hamiltonian for this Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
H=p\dot{q}-L
\end{equation}
where 
$\pi=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}$, as usual.
Since both formulations share the same dynamics, I expect the Hamilton's equations
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}=-\dot{\pi} \\
\frac{\partial H}{\partial \pi}=\dot{q}
\end{eqnarray}
to give the same dynamics. However, I do not have a consistent argument to show why this boundary term will not modify the expression for the momentum. In particular, I have no reason to impose, for example, that $\frac{\partial \dot{L_2}}{\partial q}=0$.

Even further, If I consider this Lagrangian as a higher-derivative Lagrangian and I try to apply Ostrogradsky formalism, I will eventually realize that the non-degeneracy condition fails, i.e, $\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial \dot{q}^2}= 0$.

So, anyone can instruct me how total derivative terms modify the definitions in the Hamiltonian?
Thx in advance.

Comment: canonical momentum isn't unique; for a physically relevant example, consider minimal coupling of electrodynamics, with the expression for canonical momentum depending on the choice of gauge

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202330/2451