# Legendre transform and coordinate system independence

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I'm self-learning analytical mechanics.

Consider a classical mechanical system. Even if it's clear to me that via (the usual) Legendre transform we can get a unique Hamiltonian function from a Lagrangian (at least for well suited cases), what does happen if we change the coordinate system? AFAIK the relation has to be independent from coordinate change, but how to prove it?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202330/2451

Comment: Thanks @Qmechanic. Are you in particular recommending the 6th point in your answer?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.