# Adding a term to the Lagrangian Density without changing Lagrange's Equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, textbook-erratum, boundary-terms

I'm stuck on a problem in the last chapter of Hamill's Student's Guide to Lagrangians and Hamiltonians. It asks why adding:

$$
\frac {\partial \mathscr{L}} {\partial t} + \frac {\partial \mathscr{L}} {\partial x}
$$

to the Lagrangian density $\mathscr{L}$ won't change Lagrange's equations.

I've tried starting from Lagrange's equations themselves and from Hamilton's principle, but I can't get the new terms to cancel out. I also know that if the partial derivatives were of the variation, I could integrate and the variation would be zero at the boundary - but this hasn't really helped. Any help would be much appreciated!

References:

1. P. Hamill, *A Student’s Guide to Lagrangians and Hamiltonians,* 2014; problem 7.1 p. 166.

Comment: The linked post assumes that the fields go to zero at the boundary, but I don't think we can assume the Lagrangian density goes to zero at the boundary can we?

Comment: Nevermind, of course the variation of the Lagrangian density has to be zero at the boundaries. Thanks for pointing me to that link!

Comment: Related : [Squaring the E&M (Maxwell) field strength tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/481903/squaring-the-em-maxwell-field-strength-tensor/486654#486654).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various issues with problem 7.1:

1. Firstly, when reading chapter 7, it becomes clear that Hamill confusingly is denoting a total spacetime derivative $d/d x^{\mu}$ as $\partial/\partial x^{\mu}$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321668/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. Secondly, for dimensional reasons, the function $F^{\mu}$ in the change in the Lagrangian density $$\Delta{\cal L}~=~\sum_{\mu=0}^3dF^{\mu}/d x^{\mu}\tag{*}$$ must be different than the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ itself.
3. Thirdly, for given boundary conditions (BCs), the change (*) of the Lagrangian density may destroy the existence of the [functional/variational derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112036/2451) Phys.SE post.

Altogether, this makes the corrected problem 7.1 effectively a duplicate of e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87628/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

1. P. Hamill, *A Student’s Guide to Lagrangians and Hamiltonians,* 2014; problem 7.1 p. 166.