# How can we do this tensor product $F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, action

Iam Studying "Quantization of the electromagnetic field using Quantum Field Theory" by Lahiri and Pal.

But I don't get how they computed action in equation $8.23$.

$$A=-{1\over 4} \int d^4xF_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}=-{1\over2}\int d^4 x [(\partial _\mu A_ {\nu})(\partial ^\mu A^ {\nu})-(\partial _\mu A_ {\nu})(\partial ^\nu A^ {\mu}) ]~.$$

I don't get how they evaluated 
      $~F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}~$ and arrived at this result , can any one please help me?

Comment: Related : [Squaring the E&M (Maxwell) field strength tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481903/).

Comment: Start from the definition of $F^{\mu \nu}$ and show us how far you get, we should see an attempt at a solution.

Comment: I know to evaluate second term in this integral, your link suggests an answer which only focuses on evaluation of this second term, my question is more fundamental  than that @Frobenius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand $F_{\mu\nu}$ and $F^{\mu\nu}$ and multiply. Since $\mu,\nu$ are summed over, in the next step, they can be interchanged so that $$(\partial_\mu A_\nu)(\partial^\mu A^\nu)=(\partial_\nu A_\mu)(\partial^\nu A^\mu).$$ Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok I get some ensight, I am forget about einstein's  summation rule, any way thanks a lot. I get answer but it is multiplied  by a minus sign , can you please define  $F^{\mu\nu} $ and $F_{\mu  \nu} $ @SRS

Comment: @ROBINRAJ I am not sure what you are really asking. By definition, $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$ and $F^{\rho\sigma}=\eta^{\rho\nu}\eta^{\sigma\mu}F_{\mu\nu}=\partial^\rho A^\sigma-\partial^\sigma A^\rho$.

Answer (score 1):

I briefly state main steps:

1) Using antisymetry of $F_{\mu\nu}$
$$
F_{\mu\nu}\partial^\mu A^\nu = -F_{\mu\nu}\partial^\nu A^\mu
$$
$$A=-{1\over 4} \int d^4xF_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}=-{1\over2} \int d^4 xF_{\mu\nu}\partial ^\mu A^\nu$$

2) You need use $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$

Comment: I don't get your equation 1 , I know $F_{\mu \nu}$  is an antisymmetric tensor but $\partial _{\mu } A_{\nu } $ is not @Nikita

Comment: Write $F_{\mu\nu} = \frac12(F_{\mu\nu}-F_{\nu\mu})$

Comment: I edited answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Can you define $F^{\mu \nu } $

Comment: It is as usual, but with upper indeces

Comment: Which one is correct $F^{\mu\nu} = \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu$ or $F^{\mu\nu} = \partial^\nu A^\mu - \partial^\mu A^\nu$   ? different sourses give different definition  @Nikita

Comment: Of course first