# Integrating by parts differentiated vector fields in Lagrangian

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, integration

[image]

when surface terms being ignored, from p.556, ch.26 QFT lectures of Sidney Coleman

To get this result, do I have to integrate by parts twice? Do I have to switch the derivatives around and how?

Additional: how does dropping surface terms make these two different expressions equal?

Comment: Duplicate : [Squaring the E&M (Maxwell) field strength tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481903/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Squaring the E&M (Maxwell) field strength tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481903/)