# Rewriting Maxwell Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, classical-field-theory

I'm having some problems with rewriting the Maxwell Lagrangian. The text states, \begin{align}\mathcal{L}&=-\dfrac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-A_\mu J^\mu \\
&= -\dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A_\nu)^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2-A_\mu J^\mu.\end{align}

I see that we are just using $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$ and I  understand how we get the first term. But, in order to get the second term we would need $$(\partial_\mu A_\nu)(\partial^\nu A^\mu) = (\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2.$$

Am I missing something here and if not why is $(\partial_\mu A_\nu)(\partial^\nu A^\mu) = (\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2$?

Comment: Which text? Which page?

Comment: The two formulae given for the Lagrangian density differ, but only by a total derivative, so obtain the same physics. In particular, you should find the difference is a multiple of $\partial_\mu(A^\mu\partial_\nu A^\nu-A_\nu\partial^\nu A^\mu)$.

Comment: Duplicate 1 : [Squaring the E&M (Maxwell) field strength tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/481903/squaring-the-em-maxwell-field-strength-tensor).